# Deploy Nodejs SSL Auth

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, ngrok, mutual-authentication

I build a small app that request browser certificates on server startup.

*I used a sel-signed ssl with commands above, I think this might be the problem...

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout server_key.pem -out server_cert.pem -nodes -days 365 -subj "/CN=localhost/O=Client\ Certificate\ Demo"
```

The code is basically:

```
const opts = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('server_key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server_cert.pem'),
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
}
const server = https.createServer(opts, app);
```

This is working fine on localhost (https):

[image]

Now I need to make this available for someone to test

[1. Heroku won't work](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls)

[2. azure won't work either](https://www.novatec-gmbh.de/en/blog/mutual-authentication-azure-app-service-node-js/)

So, looking for other options I found ngrok, localtunnel and such

I manage to deploy to all of them, but none asks for certificates

For ngrok I used command ngrok http https://localhost:3000
Still, https won't ask for certificate

[image]

Comment: Glad you were able to get this working locally... I never could get this to work at all the last time I tried it!  Ngrok paid accounts support proxying at the TCP level, which will probably work for you.  Otherwise, you're going to have to actually deploy your application somewhere that you have better control, like on a cheap VPS on Digital Ocean or something.

Comment: thank you, but I don't know why don't work EXACTLY, and I'm afraid to spend money on something that will not solve. Do you think it's only the self signed cert or has something to do with azure's link problem?

Comment: I'm sure it's because those other proxies are terminating SSL, so none of that level of communication even reaches your server until that connection is made and the HTTP request itself is made over that connection.

Comment: I managed to do it using ssl renegotiation and pagekite. But I found out this is kind of wrong, a client asked me to do it (and did not paid)